# Nested ng-option inside angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

Im currently trying to nest a `<select>` inside a `div` with a `ng-repeat`

something like this:

```
       <li ng-repeat="item in items >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <span ng-bind="item.Name"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 modal-body--ul--li__dropdown_container">
                    <select ng-model="typemodel" >
                        <option ng-repeat="usertype in item.userGroups"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <a ng-click="add(item)"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

In the controller im adding the item to a new list with selected items. I also want to add the value from the dropdown as a new value to the list in the controller.

```
$scope.add = function (item) {

    //New value with the value from the dropdown
    item.recipientType = typemodel;
    $scope.selected.push(item);
};
```

The list :

```
$scope.items = [  
     {           
        "Name":"Name1",
        "userGroups":[
            { "type": "gruop1" },
            { "type": "gruop2" },
            { "type": "group3" }            
        ]
     },
     {  
        "Name":"Name2",
        "userGroups":[
            { "type": "gruop1" },
            { "type": "gruop2" },
            { "type": "group3" }            
        ]
     }
    ]
```

In short i need the selected value from the dropdown when i hit the "add", the value of the current typemodel.

This is how it looks now, but it dont work. I know i have to get the correct model and maybe track the items list  by $index, but after searching the web the whole day for a solution, im still stuck!

All help is appreciated.

-Thanks!

ps. please comment if something is missing from the question, or something more is needed to solve this.

Comment: After reading whole story, i don't get what you want to have?

Comment: im sorry, meybe it was a bit unclear... I need the value of the current selected option, just for that current item.

Comment: @Rinrub take a look at my answer, I suppose I got your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your dropdown list to

```
<select ng-options="usertype in item.userGroups" ng-model="item.recipientType">
```

Then when you trigger the add function, item's property `recipientType` is already set.

```
$scope.add = function (item) {
    console.log(item.recipientType);
    $scope.selected.push(item);
};
```

Comment: Do you know how to set a defult value for the select aswell? Thx alot btw!!

Comment: Since you need to display dropdown list for each item in `ng-repeat`, default value of select should be with `item` either. So a proper solution is pre-process `$scope.items` and initialize `item.recipientType`.